# Вывести значение массива jQuery каждый в свой блок

Tags: jquery, массивы

Я получаю со всех span на странице с классом **warn** текст находящийся внутри тега. То есть у меня есть блок с цифрами, которые надо анимировать при прокрутке.

```
$('.warn').each(function( index, value ) { 
    percent.push($(value).text());
    console.log(percent);
});
```

При достижение прокрутки (это у меня все реализовано, поэтому нет смысла сюда вставлять  весь код  ), надо вывести в каждый span с классом warn свое значение анимированное.

```
$('.warn').css('opacity', '1');
$('.warn').animateNumber({
    number: percent // вот сюда надо вывести правильное значение
}, 500);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно передать в этот класс каждому свое значение с массива? То есть что надо вписать в значение number

Comment: что значит анимированное?

Answer (score 1):

используйте объекты а не массивы си получайте значения от ключа, задайте например каждому блоку с **.warn** **data-key** или просто id и получиться что то вроде

```
$('.warn').each(function( index, value ) { 
    id=$(this).data('key');
    percent[id]=$(value).text();
    console.log(percent);
 });
/**************************/
$('.warn').css('opacity', '1');
$('.warn').animateNumber({
    number: percent[$(this).data('key')] // вот сюда надо вывести правильное значение
}, 500);
```

Comment: Смотрите, я добавил .wrap data-key <span class="warn" data-key="13">13</span>. Остальное как вы написали, и получается что теперь идет перебор цифр в каждом .wrap. То есть у меня список из 10 .wrap в которых есть цифровые значения. И при прокрутке надо чтобы эти значения анимировались, то есть от нуля до значения указанного в .wrap. И получается что сейчас они просто анимируются все одинакого пока весь массив не пройдет, а потом выводит последнее значение во всех цкфз

Comment: Я не очень понимаю когда у вас срабатывает  скрипт с анимацией, но логика в том что бы у каждого warn был уникальный номер, по которому его можно записать в массив и следовательно  обратиться к конкретному значению когда нужно

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос пожалуйста. Обьявляю var percent = []; Цикл $('.warn').each(function( index, value ) { 
   percent = $(value).text();
  }); И если я введу console.log(percent); вне цикла, почему мне показывает только одно значение последнее?

Comment: смотря как вы записываете в объект данные, судя по всему вы перезаписываете один и тот же элемент массива. ключи должны быть уникальными